# Maximum characters limit for String and byte[] type data, to be stored in Objectbox databse

Tags: android, database, objectbox

I am using objectbox database to store entities.

```
    @Entity
    public class Book {
        @Id
        private long id;
        private int serial;

        private byte[] data; // limit?
        private String articles; // limit?
}
```

I know the limit for types like int, long, etc. But what about the String and byte[] data types?

I need to store few thousand characters in String.

What are the limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no limits set by ObjectBox.

Comment: Thanks!Curiosity: Have you tested with any limit, for example few million characters?

Comment: We have tested, but I don't remember the exact amount.

Comment: Could you tell approximately?

Comment: Sorry, this was too long ago... :)